# All project templates don't appear in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have installed Visual Studio Community 2022 with two workloads (for web applications), these workloads have a size about 5 GB. They were downloaded previously and using in [Visual Studio 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2019), so when I choose them in the installer, the required downloads required was 1.68 GB.

The downloading and installation completed successfully, but when I launched the Visual Studio 2022 to create new projects, no project templates appeared. I see only a blank solution.

I opened the installer to ensure that workloads selected or not, and they are selected.

Now, how can I find the templates?

Comment: Did you try repairing your installation? VS 2022 is still a pretty new product, and given the state of QA Microsoft has these past few years you might have hit some bug.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Open Visual Studio Installer.
Locate the Visual Studio 2022 panel and click "Modify".
On the right, in the "Installation details" menu, under "ASP.NET and web development" and then "Optional", check "Additional project templates (previous versions)".
Click "Modify" and you'll be done!

Comment: Hmm tried this and no dice for me, both the default and additional are already checked

Comment: I also had to add ".NET Framework project and item templates".  Then all was good.

Comment: Damn... that option is _so hidden_ its not even funny! I had searched for that component before and it just doesn't exist anywhere else.. it doesn't show up in the "normal" component lists at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for 2 days and this is what fixed it:

I downloaded and installed .NET SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download manually. Then I restarted the Visual Studio and all the projects showed up.

Comment: Is there a (plausible) explanation for it?