# New install of Visual Studio 2022 does not show project templates

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I recently did a new install of Visual Studio Community 2022 after uninstalling a previous install.  I selected 2 workloads: ASPNet & Web Development and .Net Desktop Development. But when launching Visual Studio I get no new project template when selecting "Create a New Project". The install is on Windows 11 machine.

[image: Screenshot of empty template dropdowns]

I tried solution at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70041859/all-project-templates-dont-appear-in-visual-studio-2022) but it did not resolve the issue. I also tried "repair" from Visual Studio installer. It also did not resolve the issue.

I expected to see new project templates (e.g., Console application)

Comment: Are there any items in those drop downs? Very weird.  It should automatically load up with the "All" option for each of those drop downs.

Comment: No.  None of the drop downs are populated.